# Python_interface_to run_CATIA_and_Hypermesh

Tags: python, catia

I am working on a python script which opens the CATIA application, runs the .CATscript, outputs a CAD file in .stp format and then used by Hypermesh, which will give out the meshed file of the geometry. However when I try to run the script, it says Dispatch error.

```
import win32com.client catapp = win32com.client.Dispatch('CATIA.Application')
os.system(executableCatiaVBS)
```

The error that appears is

> comerror: (-2147221005, 'Ung\xfcltige Klassenzeichenfolge', None, None)

Comment: Please edit the question and add some supporting code to help understand the issue. Please check the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for improving your chances of getting an appropriate solution.

Comment: `import win32com.client
catapp = win32com.client.Dispatch('CATIA.Application')
os.system(executableCatiaVBS)` The error that appears is  _comerror: (-2147221005, 'Ung\xfcltige Klassenzeichenfolge', None, None)_

Comment: I am new to coding and also to this forum. i f i make any mistakes, i sincerely apologise for that and also very mcuh loooking forward to suggestions to make it better. thanks